# SQL Select Specific Date format dd/mm/YYYY hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I want to select a record from a table where the date format stored as **'Jan 27 2015 12:00AM'**  When I select I should covert the date to the following format **'27/01/2015 00:00:00'**.

I tried the following it works for Date but not for TIME. So I used get date.

```
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date,StartDate,106), 103) + ' ' 
+ convert(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 14) as StartDate from Logistic
```

Can some one help me to convert the date format correctly.

I tried the Answer:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), StartDate, 103) 
                        + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), StartDate, 108)
```

Result: **Aug 25 201 Aug 25 2**

Comment: Does "from a table where the date format stored as 'Jan 27 2015 12:00AM' " mean, that this date is stored as string?

Comment: yes.. It is stored in varchar @Shnugo

Comment: @TomPHP check my answer.

Comment: After you've read through the multitude of answers, consider storing it in the correct datatype which is `datetime` or one of its variants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convert MMM dd yyyy HH:MM[AM|PM] to dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

```
Declare @Date VARCHAR(20) = 'Jan 27 2015 12:05AM'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date),103)
          + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CONVERT(DATETIME, @Date),108)


    Result:    27/01/2015 00:05:00
```

Comment: ur using getdate i need to use the table fiels it not working .. sorry

Comment: Can u check the question I have updated the Answer after ur query.

Answer (score 1):

Check this: Hope this answers your question...

EDIT: Hope this is the format you need:L

```
declare @d VARCHAR(100) ='Jan 27 2015 11:59AM';

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(@d AS DATE),103) + ' ' + CAST(CAST(@d AS TIME) AS VARCHAR(8))
```

I'm not used to the AM/PM format and I had assumed, that 12:00AM is midday and 12:00PM is midnight, but it is exactly the other way round... I'm a little puzzled at the moment... ;-)

```
declare @d VARCHAR(100) ='Jan 27 2015 11:59AM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);

SET @d ='Jan 27 2015 12:00AM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);

SET @d ='Jan 27 2015 12:01AM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);

--some more, just to check...
SET @d ='Jan 27 2015 10:00AM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);

SET @d ='Jan 27 2015 10:00PM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);

SET @d ='Jan 27 2015 00:00AM';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@d,100);
```

Comment: its converting to datetime not in the formate i needed. your output is 2015-08-25 00:00:00.000

Comment: @TomPHP, Please copy my few SQL lines into a SQL window and execute... The first three are the most interesting. Obviously your example with "12AM" is reflected as midnight and comes back with "00:00:00"

Comment: @TomPHP, I misread your question a little... Anyway, there's an example in my answer which leads to the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can do It in following, first convert to `DATE` and `TIME`, after It convert to `NVARCHAR` datatype:

```
DECLARE @dt VARCHAR(200)='Jan 27 2015 10:00AM';

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),CONVERT(DATE,@dt,103),103) + ' ' + 
       CAST(CAST(@dt AS TIME(0)) AS NVARCHAR(20));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
27/01/2015 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Convert your varchar (from format 100) to datetime. Then convert the datetime you get, into formats 103 (for date) and 108 (for time). Finally concatenate the format 103 date and format 108 time.

```
--  'Jan 27 2015 12:00AM' --> '27/01/2015 00:00:00'
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATETIME,'Jan 27 2015 12:00AM',100),103)
  +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CONVERT(DATETIME,'Jan 27 2015 12:00AM',100),108)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) it to `date` using style 100 and convert back to `VARCHAR` using style 120.

```
DECLARE @yourdate VARCHAR(100)='Jan 27 2015 12:00AM';

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATETIME,@yourdate,100),120),'-','/');
```

**Output**

```
2015/01/27 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
declare @strDate varchar(max)='Jan 27 2015 12:00AM'


select Convert(varchar(50),CONVERT(datetime, @strDate, 100),103)+' '+
cast(convert(time,@strDate,108) as varchar(8))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will go a long way towards helping current and future readers understand your answer even better.